# How do you slice each variable in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a data frame called `car` and I want to make a new column 'Brand' which is the first word of the column data 'name'.

Input dataframe:

```
mpg cylinders   displacement    horsepower  weight          name
0   18.0        8               307.0       130.0           chevrolet chevelle malibu
1   15.0        8               350.0       165.0           buick skylark 320
2   18.0        8               318.0       150.0           plymouth satellite
3   16.0        8               304.0       150.0           amc rebel sst
4   17.0        8               302.0       140.0           ford torino
```

First I find where the first word ends:

```
cars['brandno'] = cars['name'].str.find(' ')
```

And then I've sliced the word with `brandno` like:

```
cars['brand'] = cars['name'].str[:'brandno']
```

Result:

```
mpg cylinders   displacement    horsepower  weight      name                        brand   brandno
0   18.0        8               307.0       130.0       chevrolet chevelle malibu   NaN     9.0
1   15.0        8               350.0       165.0       buick skylark 320           NaN     5.0
2   18.0        8               318.0       150.0       plymouth satellite          NaN     8.0
3   16.0        8               304.0       150.0       amc rebel sst               NaN     3.0
4   17.0        8               302.0       140.0       ford torino                 NaN     4.0
```

However, as can be seen in the reuslt, it does not work. How can I solve this?

Comment: `cars['brandno'] = cars['name'].str.split().str[0]` ?

Comment: Please do not vandalise your posts. It makes more work for other people and is disrespectful of the people who have already tried to help you.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use pd.Series.apply()

```
cars['brandno'] = cars['name'].apply(lambda x: x.split(" ")[0])
# This should make a new column having only the first name of the cars
```

Answer (score 0):

May be below will work for you :

```
cars['brand'] = cars.name.str.split(expand=True)[0]
```